# Chinese IME input method in AZERTY on windows (Google IME)

Tags: windows, chinese, ime

I'm using a Belgian Azerty keyboard.
The chinese input method on Mac OS works just fine,
but on Windows, if I use the Google IME for example, 
a = z
q = w 
etc... so it uses a qwerty layout even though my keyboard is azerty.

Can I make Google IME use an azerty layout,
or is there other software that uses the azerty layout instead of qwerty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the "chinese keyboard layout changer" tool with success, you can find a download link and instructions here: http://ahmedej.blogspot.be/2011/09/chinese-input-with-non-qwerty-keyboards.html

edit: I'll quote how to manually edit the registry:

> 1. Fire up Registry Editor (regedit.exe).
> 2. Navigate to[
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts
>      ]and export this key for backup purposes.
> 3. Locate the subkey that represents the locale of your keyboard.
>      For example the French locale can be found in key 0000040c
> 4. Write down the value of the Layout File key of your chosen
>      locale. For example, for the French locale it is KBDFR.DLL
> 5. Locate the Chinese locale you want to change. For example, for
>      the Chinese (Simplified) locale look for a subkey that ends with 0804.
> 6. Change the value of the Layout File key of the Chinese locale
>      with the value of the Layout File key you have written down in Step 4.
> 7. You can optionally change the value of the Layout Text key of
>      the Chinese locale. For example you can change “Chinese (Simplified) -
>      US Keyboard” into “Chinese (Simplified) – French Keyboard”.
> 8. Restart your computer and you are all set!

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm, thank you :)