# How to input Chinese (Microsoft Pinyin) in a Japanese keyboard layout PC?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

So my PC has a Japanese keyboard layout:

[image]

I added English (Japanese Keyboard), so I can type English correctly. (striking key next to `P` got `@`)

But if I use Chinese (Microsoft Pinyin), I get `[` when typing `@` key.

How can I change the keyboard layout used in Microsoft Pinyin?

Answer (score 0):

Locate the registry.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000804`

Set `Layout File` as `KBD106.DLL` (required).

Set `Layout Text` as `Chinese (Simplified) - 106 Keyboard` (optional).

Reboot the system and it should works.

After this, you should use `Shift + Caps` to toggle `Caps Lock`.

Note:

- `0x0804 (2052)` is `zh_CN`.
- Use `KBDJPN.DLL` in Win10 1803 and older.

Ref:

- [Similar Answer](https://superuser.com/a/870531/1892685)
- [Microsoft Forum (Chinese)](https://answers.microsoft.com/zh-hans/windows/forum/all/%e4%b8%ad%e6%96%87%e8%be%93%e5%85%a5%e6%b3%95/0d84e4fa-1b43-49ef-bef4-8dce1e1204df?page=5)
- [Microsoft LCID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f)

Answer (score -1):

Please check if the following methods were helpful.

Open Settings-->Time & Language-->Language-->Click Spelling, typing & keyboard settings on the right side of the language panel-->Turn on Multilingual text suggestions under Hardware keyboard

Comment: No, there is no help:(